# What's the policy on accepting minor edits (spelling/grammar) in questions that are `on hold`?

Tags: discussion, editing, reviews

There is, in the "Suggested Edits" queue, a question that is [on hold]. 100% of the edits are minor spelling and grammar fixes. If we accept those edits, this question will go into the Reopen Queue, despite not actually being changed to address the issues.

What's are policy on these edits? Should we reject them, to prevent the question going into Reopen Queue?

Answer (score 2):

It still improves the question so they should be accepted. Reviewers in the Reopen queue should keep an eye on these edits and skip the review for the moment if it's only such a minor fix.

Comment: ...unless, of course, the reviewer disagrees with the closure in the first place, at which point the edit is largely immaterial to the decision of whether to keep closed or to reopen. The close/reopen review process is based on the idea of people with experience with the site's scope make judgement calls about a question's on-topic-ness *in its then-current form*. If a sufficient number of people agree on a question being off topic or on topic, it gets put on hold or reopened, respectively. A question shouldn't be reopened *just* because it is in reopen review, same as the other way around.

Comment: Do note the difference between *Skip* (not making a decision) and *Keep Closed* (making the decision that the edit does not improve the question sufficiently that it should be reopened). If the edit is only for spelling and grammar, and the reviewer agrees that the question shouldn't be open in its current form, then *Keep Closed* is *probably* a better choice than is *Skip*.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling I remember reading somewhere that you can't vote to *Leave Closed* more than once, but if you *Skip*ped a review it can reappear in your queue if the original asker edits it. Therefore I'd rather *Skip* if someone else fixes a few typos and wait for the OP to edit his question and use my vote on that one. Though I can't find that post right now... Well, if I don't feel right about voting on something with only minor fixed then *Skip* is the right choice for me and others who feel comfortable voting in that case should handle it. That's what *Skip* is for after all.

Comment: *"if I don't feel right about voting on something with only minor fixed then Skip is the right choice for me"* Right. If you don't want to vote in the review queue, regardless of the exact reason why, then *Skip* is indeed the proper choice.